# How to draw numbers in each Tile grid in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a Sudoku GUI and so far, I can draw the grid but I cannot display values on each tile. So far, I copied some of the code from another thread on how to display a value on a grid on pygame, and applied that so it displays a value on that tile, but instead of showing the values of individual tiles, it's lumping all the numbers in the same corner and I can't figure out how to fix it. Any help as to why I can't display the text in each individual tile of my Tile class? Here's some of my code:

```py
    class Tile:
    '''Represents each white tile/box on the grid'''
    def __init__(self, value, window, x1, x2):
        self.value = value #value of the num on this grid
        self.rows = 9
        self.cols = 9
        self.width = 60
        self.height = 60
        self.window = window #the window/screen we're in
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x1, x2, self.width, self.height) #dimensions for the rectangle

    def draw(self):
        '''Draws a tile on the board'''
        pygame.draw.rect(self.window, (0,0,0), self.rect, 1)
        pygame.display.flip()

    def display(self):
        '''Displays a number on that tile'''
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 50)
        text = font.render(str(self.value), True, (0, 0, 0))
        rect = text.get_rect() #Returns a new rectangle covering the entire surface
        self.window.blit(text, rect)
        pygame.display.update()
```

```py
   class Board:
    '''A sudoku board made out of Tiles'''
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.board = Sudoku([
            [5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
            [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
            [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
            [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
            [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]
        ])
        self.window = window
        self.tiles = [[0 for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)]

    def draw_board(self):
        '''Fills the board with Tiles'''
        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(9):
                if j%3 == 0 and j != 0: #vertical lines
                    pygame.draw.line(self.window, (0, 0, 0), (((j//3)*180)+1, 0), (((j//3)*180)+1, 540), 5)
                    pygame.display.flip()

                if i%3 == 0 and i != 0: #horizontal lines
                    pygame.draw.line(self.window, (0, 0, 0), (0, ((i//3)*180)+1), (540, ((i//3)*180)+1), 5)
                    pygame.display.flip()

                self.tiles[i][j] = Tile(self.board.get_board()[i][j], self.window, i*60, j*60) #draw a single tile
                self.tiles[i][j].draw()
                self.tiles[i][j].display()
```

The output:
[image: The numbers are all in the upper left corner instead of being in each tile?]

Comment: There's nothing in your code that would change the coordinates of the text you're drawing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be worth using a coordinate instead of a rectangle object when using the blit method. This way you could pass an argument for where you want the number to be added on the screen. You might want to make this an argument in the display method.
e.g.

```
def display(self, position):
        '''Displays a number on that tile'''
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 50)
        text = font.render(str(self.value), True, (0, 0, 0))
        self.window.blit(text, position)
        pygame.display.update()
```

You can also use some simple maths to change the position you are "blitting" the image to reflect a coordinate on the board. This may make it a bit more scalable.